# segmentation fault and xlib when starting hugin

Tags: unity, segmentation-fault

when i'd like to start hugin i get this error message:

`benjy@W520:~$ hugin`

(hugin:6376): Gtk-WARNING **: Im Modulpfad »pixmap« konnte keine Themen-Engine gefunden werden,

(hugin:6376): Gtk-WARNING **: Im Modulpfad »pixmap« konnte keine Themen-Engine gefunden werden,

(hugin:6376): Gtk-WARNING **: Im Modulpfad »pixmap« konnte keine Themen-Engine gefunden werden,

(hugin:6376): Gtk-WARNING **: Im Modulpfad »pixmap« konnte keine Themen-Engine gefunden werden,

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Speicherzugriffsfehler
benjy@W520:~$

Speicherzugriffsfehler this means segmentation fault

i have no idea what the problem could be...

Thanks for any help
greetings
benjy

Answer (score 1):

I found out myself what the problem was:

it's about the nvidia graphic card:

in the bios on my lenovo thinkpad w520 i can choose between 3 options to use the graphic card. now the problem was that the option: optimus was choosed, and ubuntu couldn't handle it right. so i disabled the optimus option, and now at least hugin works finde. and of course all 3D effects are wonderful now!